# Probability theory problem , inequality

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $a , b$ two randomly chosen positive integers not exceeding $n$.
Let $P(n)$ denote the probability that $\begin{equation} \\ a ^ 2 + b ^ 2\leq n^2 \end{equation}$. How can I find the value of $P(n)$ when $n$ tends to infinity? I know that it is easier to find the limit than the actual  probability.

Comment: I think a drawing could help you find your solution

Answer (score 2):

In virtue of the [Gauss circle problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssCircleProblem.html), the limit probability is just $\frac{\pi}{4}$.